# Merge array values to form a new array based on Index using Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

Let's say I have the following code:

```
a = ["xyz","abc","efg"]
b = [1,2,3]
```

I want to merge the array b into array a which would give me:

```
c = [["xyz",1],["abc",2],["efg",3]]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's an easy one. Use [Enumerable#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip): `c = a.zip(b)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - make it an answer.

Comment: I don't think there's a need for an answer. This same question has undoubtedly been asked many times before, so I expect it won't be long before it's closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Note the near-equivalence of [Enumerable#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) and [Array#transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) for arrays: `[a,b].transpose => [["xyz", 1], ["abc", 2], ["efg", 3]]`.  It's only "near" because `[1,2].zip([3]) => [[1, 3], [2, nil]]`, whereas `[[1,2],[3]].transpose => IndexError: element size differs (1 should be 2)`.